# Printing a string in c using a pointer

Tags: c

I have the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char * string = GetString();

    printf("%c", *(1+string));


    int j;

    for (j = 0; string[j] != '\0'; j++)
    printf("%c", *(j+string));

    int i;

    scanf("%d", &i);

    return 0;
}
```

and the function GetString

```
char *  GetString()
{
    char string[100];

    char x; // to get the chars 1 by 1
    int counter = 0;
    scanf("%c", &x); // i dont like do while loops

    while (x != '\n')
    {
        string[counter] = x;
        scanf("%c", &x);
        counter++;
    }
    string[counter] = '\0';

    char * stringg = string;

    return stringg;
}
```

for some reason, if I print the string inside the function i get normal input. but if i print it in the main i get really wierd output. what is the problem ?

Comment: Problem is that `stringg` is a local variable and you can return a pointer to it. It's [*undefined behaviour*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Although not an answer to your question (others answer that okay) -one observation is the potential buffer overrun and security threat if the number of characters read is more than 99. Probably should be checking `counter` so that it doesn't exceed the size of your array.

Comment: Also, you don't need `stringg`. When an array appears in an expression in C, it is (roughly speaking) transformed into a pointer to its first element, so you could simply `return string`.

Comment: Another problem is that your code in `main` doesn't know what your `GetString` function is. If you are using a 64 bit system, your compiler most likely will be things wrong. You should compile your code with all warnings enabled.

Answer (score 4):

When you return `stringg`, which is a pointer to the local variable `string` in `GetString`, you are returning a reference to memory that is just about to be reclaimed. This is because `string` "lives" in the [stack frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) of `GetString`, and the stack frame ceases to exist when the function returns. You have three options:

1. Move `string` to `main`, and pass a pointer to it to `GetString`.
2. Dynamically allocate `string` using `malloc` inside of `GetString`. Memory allocated using `malloc` survives until manually released using `free`.
3. Or, as Michael Petch pointed out below, declare `string` as `static`, meaning memory will be set aside in the [global data segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment#Data) of the program. However, this means that subsequent calls to `GetString` will clobber its contents, so if you want to save the result of a previous call to 
   `GetString` you must manually copy it using `strdup` or similar.

Before `GetString` returns, the stack looks something like this:

```
                       (high address)
+---------------------+
|   (main's frame)    |
|        ...          |
+---------------------+
| (GetString's frame) |
|  char string[100]   |
+---------------------+ <- stack pointer
                       (low address)
```

As you can see, the [stack pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Stack_and_frame_pointers) points to the end of `GetString`'s frame, marking the top of the stack (notice that on most modern platforms, the stack actually grows downwards). But when `GetString` returns, the stack pointer moves up to the end of `main`'s frame:

```
                       (high address)
+---------------------+
|   (main's frame)    |
|        ...          |
+---------------------+ <- stack pointer
| Formerly the frame  |
| of GetString, now   |
| (probably) garbage. |
+---------------------+
                       (low address)
```

<strike>And accessing something that is not part of the stack (i.e., in this case below the stack pointer) results in undefined behavior.</strike> (Well, not quite - see Barak Manos' comment below) In your case, you get garbage.

Comment: Another option (albeit ugly with side effects) is to define `string` as static.

Comment: Worth noting that the stack implementation (in particular the low/high address issue) is compiler-dependent and not dictated by the C-language standard, which only states that returning a local array yields undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @barakmanos. I have edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Returning pointer to automatic local variable invokes undefined behavior. You need to use dynamic allocation or use `static`specifier.

```
char *string = malloc(100);
```

or

```
static char string[100];
```

Comment: Or global variable `char string[100]`... Or allocating it in `main` and passing it to `GetString`.

Comment: I would not recommend a `static` local string either, because both are thread-unsafe. In addition, I would not recommend a constant length string without protecting it from overflowing in the `for` loop either. But all that is irrelevant to the problem at hand, which is the string's allocation-scope (or allocation segment)... In any case, if we were to discuss the most recommended option then it would probably be to pass the string from `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the array to the `GetString` function

```
void  GetString(char string[], size_t length /* prevent overflow */)
{
    char x; // to get the chars 1 by 1
    int counter = 0;

    if (length == 0)
    {
        string[0] = '\0';
        return;
    }
    scanf("%c", &x); // i dont like do while loops

    while ((x != '\n') && (counter < length - 1))
    {
        string[counter] = x;
        scanf("%c", &x);
        counter++;
    }
    string[counter] = '\0';
}
```

and in `main`

```
int main()
{
    char string[100];

    GetString(string, sizeof(string));
    if (*string != '0')
        printf("%c", *(1+string));

    int j;
    for (j = 0; string[j] != '\0'; j++)
        printf("%c", *(j+string));
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is a good idea to follow the DRY (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. Also `GetString()` fails for a length of 0.

Comment: It still fails for lenght = 0.

Answer (score 0):

[too long for a comment]

To follow up on [*iharob*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983495/iharob) [proposal to pass in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27582066/694576), please see this:

```
int GetString(char * str, size_t len)
{
  int result = 0;

  if ((NULL == str) || (0 == len))
  {
    result = -1;
    errno = EINVAL;
  }
  else 
  {
    while (1 < len)
    {
      result = scanf("%c", str);
      if (EOF == result)
      {
        int errno_save = errno:

        if (ferror(stdin))
        {
          result = -1;
          errno = errno_save;
        }
        else
        {
          result = 0;
        }
      }

      if ((0 != result) || ('\n' == *str))
      {
        break;
      }

      ++str;
      --len;
    }

    *str = '\0';
  }

  return result;
}
```

Call this like so:

```
int main()
{
  char string[100];

  int result = GetString(string, sizeof(string));
  if (-1 == result)
  {
    perror("GetString()" failed");
    exit(1);
  }

  ...
```